# yii2 Webhook post empty

Tags: php, yii2

I am kinda new to the yii FrameWork, and i need help.

i need to implement a stripe webhook controller that is used for the subscription event sent by Stripe. 
For this controller, there is no view nor model

I can access to the controller, but the $_POST content is empty and i cannot figure why.

Is it possible to use the post verb without a view ?

here's an example :

```
class StripeWebhookController extends Controller
{
     public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if ($action->id == 'index') {
          $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
         }

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

public function actionIndex()
{   
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    StripeLoader::autoload();
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( Settings::get("stripe_secret_key") );
       // retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
       $input = file_get_contents('php://input'); // -> here $input is null

      $event_json = json_decode($input, true);

    //      Do the work...
}
```

i used the

```
 print_r(Yii::$app->request->post() /*$_POST*/); exit();
```

and i only got an empty array.

After days of search i found nothing...

If any one has an idea, i will gladly take it

Additionnal info : we are running on a IIS web server, using the Yii2 framework

Thanks for reading me
cya

Answer (score 7):

For anyone similarly stuck, I had to do the following to get this working:

**Disable CSRF protection for the whole class**

`public $enableCsrfValidation = false;`

**Use getRawBody() instead of post()**

`$data = json_decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody());`

Outside the framework you would use `file_get_contents("php://input")`

**Avoid any server side redirects**

In my case that meant no trailing slash or www. in the URL

Answer (score 0):

If `Yii::$app->request->post()` is empty then the request has not POST data. Grab the request in beforeAction and dump the entire thing. That will be what your machine is receiving. If empty, the machine is not receiving the data being sent with the request.

Comment: I tried what you asked, and this is what going out : 
     Array ( )
So i gess the controller is not receiving anything. 
Another test i made : 
     ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  
gives me a get... soooooo i an confused

Comment: That tells me the server is receiving an empty request; _POST would indeed be empty then. This makes me think the failure is earlier in the process execution.

Comment: You think that IIS wil refuse the POST verb just on that controller then ?

Comment: Maybe, but then I would think it would deny all POST requests. I'd check the Yii router, that c/would.

Comment: Ok i am looking for that. If i find anything i'll let you know

Comment: Well it doesn't seems to be that :(