# Facebook Messenger Bot: Not receiving POST request from FB

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Weird thing is happening, I have registered my webhook and setup up everything, but now I am not receiving POST requests anymore when I am talking to my bot. FB only sends me GET requests to the webhook when I send a message.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be and how I can look for a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _“FB only sends me GET requests to the webhook when I send a message”_ – I really doubt that. First of all, check whether your webhook is _still_ correctly registered - it might get disabled, if your bot does not send proper responses for a while. If it was disabled, then perhaps Facebook is sending you the initial verification data again (and that would indeed happen via GET.) If that’s not it, then I suggest you first of all check what your server receives, via the relevant log files, and how it responds (like is there maybe an incorrect redirect that could cause that, ...)

Comment: OK thanks, I'll check that.
The only thing that I get from FB is a GET request without parameters.. at least I would expect the webhook verification parameters.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I'm having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I cant remember what solved the issue :/

Answer (score 3):

Re-authenticate your page.

```
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The request results at the moment in `OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active accounts due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform"`, which has something to do with the changes in FB policies, so that makes sense for me. Have to use the Try-Later approach

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saved me hours :)

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and spent a lot of hours banging my head on the wall before I found this:
[yii2 Webhook post empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679454/yii2-webhook-post-empty)

Not sure if its the same problem the OP had, but I think is usefull to leave it here anyway: the hook was being called with POST, not get, and the data was being sent, but PHP does not receives it on the $_POST, and so it looked like a GET (because Yii::$app->request->post() returns false). But then I logged $_SERVER and it was actually a POST request, except $_POST was empty. Then I found that answer

To retrieve the data facebook sends on PHP, you need either have to use

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input")
```

or, if you use the Yii framework:

```
$data = json_decode(Yii::$app->request->getRawBody());
```